# Configure method not called in springboot 3.0.9- Issue during migration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-3

I'm migrating from springboot 2.7.7 to springboot 3.0.9.
I've used openrewrite to make the package changes.
The application doesn't work after the 3.0.9 upgrade.
I'm building a war file and deploying it to tomcat manually.
I'm able to debug that the configure() method in the main class isn't called.

This is also has subprojects.
The pom.xml below is the main pom

**DoceditApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "be.schaubroeck.docedit",
        "be.schaubroeck.esse.docedit"
})
@EnableScheduling
public class DoceditApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor()
    {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DoceditApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.sources(DoceditApplication.class);
    }

   
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean restApiV1Jersey()
    {
        ServletRegistrationBean v1Jersey = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(new JerseyConfig()));
        v1Jersey.addUrlMappings("/v1/api/*");
        v1Jersey.setName("Rest API V1");
        v1Jersey.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        return v1Jersey;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.schaubroeck.docedit</groupId>
    <artifactId>docedit-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>docedit-boot</name>
    <description>Spring Boot app
    </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>be.schaubroeck.docedit</groupId>
        <artifactId>docedit-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>be.schaubroeck.docedit</groupId>
      <artifactId>docedit-rest-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.lookfirst</groupId>
            <artifactId>sardine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.8</version>
      </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>be.schaubroeck.esse</groupId>
            <artifactId>docedit-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-A.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>atlas-compat-hib36-spring25</artifactId>
                    <groupId>be.schaubroeck.atlas</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>atlas-config</artifactId>
                    <groupId>be.schaubroeck.atlas</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.runnable.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>be.schaubroeck.docedit</groupId>
                            <artifactId>docedit-rest-api</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>
                    <embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
                        <initInfoChkconfig>2345 92 08</initInfoChkconfig>
                    </embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultOutputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
                    </defaultOutputDirectory>
                    <processors>
                        <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                    </processors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bower uninstall checkpoint-ria</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bower</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>uninstall checkpoint-ria --no-color --allow-root</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bower update</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bower</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>update --no-color --allow-root</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>grunt build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>grunt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.23.0</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateVersionJs</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/" />
                                <property name="app.name" value="doceditApp" />

                                <copy file="${src.dir}/version_tpl.js" tofile="${src.dir}/version.js" overwrite="true" />
                                <replace file="${src.dir}/version.js" token="@appname@" value="${app.name}" />
                                <replace file="${src.dir}/version.js" token="@version@" value="${version}" />
                                <replace file="${src.dir}/version.js" token="@buildtime@" value="${maven.build.timestamp}" />
                                <echo message="version.js aangemaakt voor ${version}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>uitvoerenGrunt</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                <if>
                                    <available file="dist" />
                                    <then>
                                        <echo message="Distro available !" />
                                        <copy todir="target/dist">
                                            <fileset dir="dist" />
                                        </copy>
                                    </then>
                                    <else>
                                        <echo message="Distro not available, using source..." />
                                        <copy todir="target/dist">
                                            <fileset dir="app" />
                                        </copy>
                                    </else>
                                </if>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
                        <version>20020829</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are upgrading Spring Boot which also means you need to upgrade the server you deploy to to one that supports JakartaEE. Apparently you aren't doing that.